# How does Credit Karma have access to my information

Tags: credit, credit-karma-tax

How does credit karma get access to my information? When I sign up and give them my personal details, whom do they get my credit info from (such as open credit cards, credit scores,etc.)?

Comment: https://www.creditkarma.com/faq/howitworks

Answer (score 4):

The credit scores and credit reports you see on Credit Karma come directly from TransUnion and Equifax, two of the three major consumer credit bureaus. They should accurately reflect your credit information as reported by those bureaus.

The scores they show are calculated using the VantageScore 3.0 model, which is just one of many credit score formulas available, and not necessarily the one lenders or other credit providers will utilize.